# Sorting XML according to certain tag

Tags: python, xml

I have a very large file containing alot of XML tags. to make it easy lets use owners and pets as an example

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PetOwnertag>
  <owner>Bob</owner>
  <pet>Fluffers</pet>
</PetOwnertag>
<PetOwnertag>
  <owner>Jim</owner>
  <pet>Mr.Whiskers</pet>
</PetOwnertag>
```

The thing I wanna do is be able to have a script load in the XML file and sort the content of the file acording to the name of the Owner, so everyowner who starts with 'B' goes in File1.xml and everyone else goes in File2.xml.

How would i go about making this the easiest way possible? I preferly should do it in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, u can use [lxml](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) to load your XML file. 
u store the Owner and his EtreeElement in a dict (like hashmap). 
U sort the dict by Owner and than get the elements from the dict and write in output files.

Example (not tested)

```
from lxml import parse
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO

tree = etree.parse(StringIO("your file name"))
data_dict = dict()
for child in tree:
   # Element.tag return the PetOwnerTag. So u must go into, search the element by tag owner and get his value
   # data_dict[child.tag] = child
   owner = child.find("owner")
   if owner:
       data_dict[owner.text] = child

for owner in sorted(data_dict.iterkeys()):
    # here can u write your data to files
    print owner, etree.tostring (dict[owner])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the lxml lib, and store them in EtreeElements in a dictionary